# In what situations would a native English speaker omit the last g in an -ing verb?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Examples:

> I'm sick of following my dreams. I'm just going to ask them where they're goin', and hook up with them later.
>
> *-Mitch Hedberg*
>
> The jazz boom was goin' on then so there was a lot happenin' in New York at that time.
>
> *-Mose Allison*

The first speaker left out the -g in the second going, but not in the first. Why? When would a native English speaker omit it and when not?

(I'm interested in both oral and written form. But I guess the written omission is just to represent the former?)

Comment: Do you mean when they change the pronunciation from [iŋ] to [in] or do you mean when they change the spelling from *‑ing* to *‑in*?  The former is quite common, while the latter is used only to represent eye-dialect.  This is one area where speech and writing have diverged. The picture is more complicated than this, and I feel we do have some questions on it already, but it’s late and I must sleep now.

Comment: Are you asking about when a writer writes "goin'", or are you asking about when a speaker pronounces "going" with a "n" at the end? (Practically no one says a "g" at the end of "going".)

Comment: The short answer is, *whenever they feel like it*.  There are lots of reasons and a lot of them can't be guessed by an outside observer.  If they wanted to enunciate clearly they might be more likely to leave it in, but even then a given regional dialect might be more likely to leave it off or vice versa.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I think you're right that the written omission is generally used to represent the spoken. In writing, you'd virtually never omit the 'g' unless reproducing speech.

Comment: @GregLee We almost all pronounce the "g" in the sense of the sound represented by "ng" instead of just "n." You likely mean that we don't add a hard "g" as at the beginning of "grow."

Comment: related: [Pronunciation of '-ing' endings as '-een'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103866/pronunciation-of-ing-endings-as-een); [Waiteen for waiting](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/waiteen-for-waiting); [Dropped g's in upper-class 1930s Britain](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3853/dropped-gs-in-upper-class-1930s-britain)

Comment: And the nearest question I could find is on pronounciation: [-ing vs -in' ending](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59653/ing-vs-in-ending)

Comment: I really think you should consider putting a small bounty on this question tomorrow. It deserves much more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a rule, but dropping the "g" happens much more often before a vowel.

Comment: Even when dropped in "going to" it's changed to "gonna" so than the "n" sound is before a vowel.

Comment: Oooh, and my favourite dropped "g" in "going" is when "I'm going to" is pronounced "I'ma" as in "I'ma getchoo."

Answer (score 0):

Taking *going* as an example, I hear 3 pronunciations: (1) *goin'* [goɪn], (2) *going* [goiŋ], (3) [goin].  The forms in brackets are the pronunciations in phonetic notation.  Notice that none of the pronunciations ends in phonetic [g].  There are two syllables in each of the pronunciations.  The [ɪ] sound is the vowel of *hit*, *tin*, ...  The [i] sound is the vowel of *he*, *wheat*, ... The [ŋ] sound is the nasal consonant in *think* -- there is no letter in conventional spelling that corresponds to it.

(1) is either a dialectal form or one used to indicate a casual conversational tone. (2) is the maximally distinct form you might use if you were worried about misunderstanding, but otherwise, I would almost never use it.  (3) is my normal pronunciation and the one I often hear.  An approximation in conventional spelling would be *go-een*.