# The NG sound in casual American speech

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I read somewhere (I don't remember the source and I'm not sure if it's true) that Americans tend to replace the "ng" sound with only "n" in casual/fast speech.

For example: Who's calling? sounds like [huz ˈkɔ lɪn] instead of [huz ˈkɔ lɪŋ]. The difference is between the two sounds: **n** and **ŋ**

Is it true?

Comment: That's not limited to AmE, it's found all over the Anglosphere. It is, however, mostly limited to the ending _-ing_ (in its various uses). _Ringing_, for example, would never be [rinin] (please excuse the bad IPA—typing on phone).

Comment: It depends on the region, dialect, and level of formality.

Comment: Yes, even Lord Peter Wimsey in his best Mayfair upper-class-twit accent would say ['rɪŋɪn]. And it's very common in America as well; certainly it's the first thing to go when speech speeds up.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Moreover, the ending _ing_ becomes _in_ only if the ending is added to a word. In a word that ends in _ing_ in its base form, such as _sing_, the [ng] would not be pronounced [n]. So in short, it's only in a specific type of situation that [ng] is replaced with [n.]

Comment: @Nicole _-ing_ is not an ending in _sing_; it's part of the root. The definition of an ending is something that is attached to a stem.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I thought it was best to clarify for OP that not all words that end in _ing_ can have the [ng] replaced with [n].

Comment: See also [regionality of g-dropping](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42386/what-kind-of-human-character-or-regional-trait-does-the-habit-of-the-g-dropping), or [g dropping in RP](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3853/dropped-gs-in-upper-class-1930s-britain)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
And that's done even in writing; you can find:

> [Sweet Dreams at the Goodnight Motel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=KKe0J_h7MCUC&pg=PA207&dq=%22Who%27s%20callin%3F%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H7onVcS0AbDisAT65oH4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Who%27s%20callin%3F%22&f=false) - Page 207 Curtiss Ann Matlock -
>   2009 -
>
> “Not if you were **callin'** Claire Wilder.”
>
> That was a surprise. “Yes, I was. Who's this?”
>
> “Who's **callin'**?” The guy, whoever he was, was a wise-ass.
>
> “This is Andrew Wilder, **callin'** my wife.”

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the "replacement" of [ŋ] with [n] is mostly restricted to word-final unstressed *-ing.*

As far as I know, it's not really clear why this happens. (I wrote a more detailed post to this effect as an answer to the question [Why does “-ing” go to “-in” in some dialects?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361756))

Almost all of the words where this sound change occurs end in the common suffix *-ing,* but it can also affect some words that don't end in this suffix, such as *something* and *nothing.*

Incidentally, the vowel in *-ing/-in'* is not necessarily realized as [ɪ].

- For speakers with the weak vowel merger (including me), unstressed /ɪn/ may not be clearly distinguished in perception from unstressed /ən/.
- Some American English speakers use /iŋ/ in place of /ɪŋ/ (in all contexts), and at least some of these speakers consequently have /in/ (with a different vowel from /ɪn/) as a variant pronunciation of the *-ing* suffix.