# Pronunciation of "string"

Tags: pronunciation

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/string) "string" is pronounced as /stɹɪŋ/. However, all of my acquaintances have split opinions about the 'g' at the end. I'm of a mind that the 'g' is pronounced, e.g. two strin**g**s, not two stri**nn**s.

I'm interested in which is the correct form and whether it's based on the language region, context, or perhaps something completely different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The NG sound in casual American speech](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238524/the-ng-sound-in-casual-american-speech)

Comment: The standard Midwest US pronunciation is slightly heaver on the "G" sound than the audio clip in that link.  There are people who pronounce it "strin", but I can't characterize where they're from.

Comment: The general phenomenon is called 'g-dropping', which name is an unfortunate artifact of spelling, but really is a change from the dental-nasal/velar-stop explicit pair /ng/ to the velar-nasal single phoneme /ŋ/.

Comment: I can't imagine any variety of English that does not pronounce 'string' as /stɹɪŋ/, even in those that do g-dropping for multisyllabic words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the North-west and North-west Midlands of England, the /g/ is regularly pronounced in words like 'sing' and 'string'. As far as I know, everywhere else in the Anglosphere it is not pronounced separately, and the final sound is /ŋ/.

Comment: In New York City, some people pronounce the /g/ if the next word begins with a vowel. Consider the stereotypical pronunciation of *Long Island* as *Long Guyland.*